# How to use custom class pointer comparator inside class being compared

Tags: c++, class, comparator

I am trying to use a custom comparator as in the following minimal example:

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct idComp;

class TestClass
{
   public:
      int id;
      void setId(int i){ id = i; }
      int getId(){ return id; }
      void test( set<TestClass*, idComp> &s){
         //do my stuff 
      }
      void test2(){
         set <TestClass*, idComp> s;
      }
};

struct idComp
{
   bool operator() (TestClass* t1, TestClass* t2) const
   {
      return t1->getId() < t2->getId();
   }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   return 0;
}
```

...but when I try to compile I get the following error relating to the `test` function:

```
comp_ref.cpp:12:34: error: ‘idComp’ was not declared in this scope
       void test( set<TestClass*, idComp> &s){
                                  ^~~~~~
comp_ref.cpp:12:40: error: template argument 2 is invalid
       void test( set<TestClass*, idComp> &s){
```

and this with the addition of `test2`:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:708:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct idComp’
       _Rb_tree_impl<_Compare> _M_impl;
```

Any suggestions of how/where to define `idComp` so that it is usable by the function `test`?

Comment: Your C++ compiler is logical entity. It reads your program from beginning to the end, and not from the end to the beginning. So, when your compiler reads your program, to compile it, and it gets to the `void test( set<TestClass*, idComp> &s)` part, how do you expect your compiler to know anything about `idComp`, at this point, even what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a bit of a circular dependency, you can resolve this by forward-declaring `idComp` before `TestClass`:

```
struct idComp;

class TestClass
{
   ...
```

But you can leave the definition of `struct idComp` where it is.

Comment: Nice. Any thoughts on the second error for test2? (edited/added to the code example)

Comment: @skellpco Not sure. Better to create another question for that.